# Can the ban on questions be shortened by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, moderators, asking-questions

6 months or more to asks another question is extreme just for asking bad questions which I thought were good. Once the asker is up to a point of bad questions regardless the length of time that passes the next poorly received question equals another 6 month ban??? I am sure I am not the only user who feels this way and I ask for not just me but for every future novice engineer enthusiast who may get stuck in this rut.

Comment: 6 months is not sure, it is possible that you've survived with only 2 weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question bans are controlled by the SE systems / algorithms.  Moderators do not have the ability to override the length of those bans.

SE typically follows a progressively increasing length of bans or suspensions.  You may find the following [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) post of relevance as it goes into a bit more detail about question bans.

Answer (score 2):

When you get banned due to excessive low quality posts, you get a explanation of what to do about it.  Follow it.

Note that pleading for the system to make a exception is NOT one of the recommended actions.

Remember that you were banned for substantive reasons.  You have done nothing to show us those reasons no longer apply.  In fact, this question re-enforces that they probably continue to apply.

Comment: This does not answer my question, I kindly ask that you refrain from contacting me since every encounter seems to me to be negative and unfriendly.

Comment: Check his questions, my opinion is that the ordinary handling of LQ posts (closure/deletion) should be enough, and these extra actions (Q&A ban, suspension) are overreactions. Particularly if you consider that his surviving posts have typically quite positive results (view counts, voting scores). These sites not exclusively for professionals, they play a significant play to *popularize* the technology and distribute the knowledge, imho his posts are very useful from this view.

Comment: @Peter: Check his questions.  Most of them are "what if" about nonsense science.  In addition, they are very poorly written to the point that much reads like gibberish.  That's not popularizing anything, just polluting the site.  We don't want that here.  By extension, we don't want him here.  He's had plenty of warnings and explanations of what to do right, but to no avail.  Now he's locked out.  Good.  Let's keep it that way.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I am sorry but not this is what I can see in his (survived) questions. No "what if" questions, these are naiv but popular science questions, with attractive effect for the google hits of the site. Furthermore, he is a child. Future generations, group interest, the future of the industrial civilization and similars would be the key concepts of my related arguments.